# Sample usage of InfVerif.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, drivers, wdk

InfVerif.exe is a new tool available with WDK10 for Driver INF verification.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn941086(v=vs.85).aspx

I am trying to run the tool but keep getting its usage message.

Can anyone show a sample of its usage with example data?

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running into the same issue. The search for answers continues.

Comment: Apparently it is broken in the Anniversary Update WDK: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/90cb9b98-c53c-4203-8f4e-e903f0419998/infverif-tool-not-working-with-windows-10-and-wdk-10?forum=wdk

Answer (score 1):

**Command:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>infverif.exe /v /u <Path to the INF file you want to verify>
```

**Output will look like this:**

Running in Verbose

Running Universal INF check

Running in Console output mode

Checking "Path to your INF file"

INF is valid

Checked 1 INF(s) in 0 m 0 s 4 ms